# ceiling fan Wiring with old house

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, old-house

How to wire up ceiling fan with a remote and receiver?
Three hot wires tied together, 4 white wires tied together, and 1 black by itself (I think it goes to light switch).

[image]

Comment: Was there a ceiling fan there before or just a light fixture? How was the previous device wired? Share the "before" pics you took before you removed all the wires from the previous device.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the light switch box please?